# How to handle keyboard short cuts ( shortcuts like Command + control )?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I get the keyCode for a particular combination in KeyDown? What would be the keyCode for `Control + Option + A`.  or `Command + Control +Shift +X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSEvent modifierFlags]` will return a bitmask of the modifier keys that are currently down (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks Mike,Your suggestion helped me in solving the issue.

By using the following code snippet I resolved the issue.
 
 **if (([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) && ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask))**